# Fetch "previous" document with mongoId

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have `Images` stored in mongoDB. They are sorted by "created_at".

Now, when I load a single item with `Image.find("documentID")` I want to access the document just before and the one just after this one, based on the `created_at` order.

For that, I have two methods and a default_scope in `image.rb`:

```
default_scope asc(:created_at)     

def previous_image
  self.class.last(:conditions => {:created_at.lt => created_at})
end

def next_image
  self.class.first(:conditions => {:created_at.gt => created_at})
end
```

Is there a native way in **mongoDB** to access the document before and after the current document?

Is there a better way to create such named scopes with **mongoID** in rails to access previous and next items, also considering performance (not querying three times for one image)?

**Edit**: The "previous_image" should use last, not first. That solves the bug of "skipping" items. The questions about the proper way to achive this remain, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may try something like this:

```
def previous_image mongoid
  self.class.find(:conditions => {:_id => {$lt: mongoid}}).sort({:_id=>-1}).limit(1)
end

def next_image mongoid
  self.class.find(:conditions => {:_id => {$gt: mongoid}}).sort({:_id=>1}).limit(1)
end
```

This approach utilizes sequentiality of Mongo ids.

Comment: I implemented a solution that is somewhat similar, because your code (`{$lt: mongoid}`) gives a syntax error.

Comment: I am comming from PHP world, tried to make it as much Ruby-friendly as I could.

Answer (score 6):

You could try something like the following, based on jhavdra's response, but rewritten for Mongoid syntax.

```
def previous_image
  self.class.where(:_id.lt => self._id).order_by([[:_id, :desc]]).limit(1).first
end

def next_image
  self.class.where(:_id.gt => self._id).order_by([[:_id, :asc]]).limit(1).first
end
```